# Request method of type post not recognized by Spring Rest Api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

This Code work fine :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/post")
public class PostController {

@Autowired
private PostService postService;

public PostService getPostService() {
    return postService;
}

public void setPostService(PostService postService) {
    this.postService = postService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/userPost", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String userPost(String username) {
    try {
        List<Validation> validations = new ArrayList<Validation>();
        ValidationHandeler.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(validations, username, "username is requierd");

        if (validations.isEmpty()) {
            List<Post> followers = getPostService().findUserPost(username);
            return new Message(followers, MessageSuccesStatusEnum.SUCCESS).toString();
        }

        return new Message(validations, MessageSuccesStatusEnum.FAILED).toString();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return new Message("Error retriving follower list : " + ex.toString(), MessageSuccesStatusEnum.FAILED)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

and this is the output :

```
{"result":"0","info":["username is requierd"]}
```

but when ever I change the RequestMethod type to post it give me the following output :

```
{"timestamp":1492948640973,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/post/userPost"}
```

does any body know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using GET instead of POST as a request method.

@RequestMapping(value = "/userPost", method = **RequestMethod.GET)**

Comment: As I sad in the post I did change the Request type to Post but not working

Comment: How are you testing the API, do you have a CURL request?

Comment: curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/post/userPost this request give 404 when method request type is post

Comment: can you try this?curl --request POST \
  --url http://hhtp//localhost:8080/api/post/userPost \
  --form username=sample

Comment: the output is : curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  --url
{"timestamp":1492951793815,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/post/userPost"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  --form
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: username=babak

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependencies>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-schema-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

TestClass TestNG
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

public class basics {

    @Test
    public void getPlaceAPI() 
    {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://maps.googleapis.com";
        given().param("location", "42.3675294,-71.186966").param("radius", 
        "10000").param("key", "").when()
        .get("/maps/api/place/textsearch/json").then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more details, in particular your ACTUAL PROBLEM, the context, what you try to achieve, what yo did to achieve it and your previous attempts to solve your problem.